# The corn plant is dying what should I do

Tags: houseplants

[image]

Corn plant. In the beginning, the soil was soaking wet; I bought new soil and let her dry with the air; one of the strips fell down, the other dried, and the only one left I dont know will survive. Is there any chance this plant will survive? What should I do? Will the others grow back? Please help, thank you

Comment: I don't think it's corn. Is it a dragon tree?  https://www.thespruce.com/grow-dracaena-marginata-indoors-1902749   Or possible a Dracaena? https://www.thespruce.com/types-of-dracaena-6825681 Also, is the green growth from the same root as the dead part?

Comment: It's a mass cane house plant.